# Why calculation code doesnt work?

Tags: javascript

so basically, please check this code -

Full code -

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
  var seasonLookup = [
      {startDay: 1, startMonth:1, endDay: 10, endMonth: 6, season:1},
      {startDay: 21, startMonth:9, endDay: 31, endMonth: 12, season:1},
      {startDay: 11, startMonth:6, endDay: 30, endMonth: 6, season:2},
      {startDay: 1, startMonth:9, endDay: 20, endMonth: 9, season:2},
      {startDay: 1, startMonth:7, endDay: 31, endMonth: 8, season:3},    
      ];

  var cars = $('#cars_input').val();

  var priceone = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('priceone'));

  var pricetwo = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('pricetwo'));

  var pricethree = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('pricethree'));

  var pricefour = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('pricefour'));

  var pricefive = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('pricefive'));

  var pricesix = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('pricesix'));

  var priceseven = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('priceseven'));

  var priceeight = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('priceeight'));   

  var pricenine = ($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('pricenine'));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

  var priceMatrix = {
      cars: {
          1: { t1: priceone, t2: pricetwo, t3: pricethree},
          2: { t1: pricefour, t2: pricefive, t3: pricesix},
          3: { t1: priceseven, t2: priceeight, t3: pricenine}
      }       
  };

  function getSeason(date){
      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth()+1;
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      for(var i=0;i<seasonLookup.length;i++){
          var s = seasonLookup[i];
          var startDate = new Date(year, s.startMonth-1,s.startDay);
          var endDate = new Date(year, s.endMonth-1,s.endDay);
          if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
              return s.season;
      }
      return null;
  }

  function getPrice(bike, season, days){
    var tier = "";
    if(days <=2)
      tier = "t1";
    else if(days <=7)    
        tier = "t2";
     else
         tier = "t3"
             console.log(days + ' days in season ' + season + ' at ' + priceMatrix[bike][season][tier] + '/day (' + tier + ')')
     return priceMatrix[bike][season][tier] * days;
  }

  function calculatePrice(startDate, endDate, bike)
  {
      console.log(startDate);
          console.log(endDate);
     var currentSeason = getSeason(startDate);
     var totalPrice = 0;
     var daysInSeason = 0;
     var currentDate = startDate;
     while(currentDate<=endDate){
         var season = getSeason(currentDate);
         if(season != currentSeason){
                totalPrice += getPrice(bike,currentSeason,daysInSeason);
                currentSeason = season;
                daysInSeason = 0;
         }
         daysInSeason++;
         currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);        
     }
      totalPrice += getPrice(bike,currentSeason,daysInSeason);
      return totalPrice;
  }

  $('.recalc').change(function(){
      var startDate = new Date(parseInt($('#year_input').val(),10),parseInt($('#month_input').val(),10)-1,parseInt($('#day_input').val(),10) );
      var endDate = new Date(parseInt($('#yearr_input').val(),10),parseInt($('#monthr_input').val(),10)-1,parseInt($('#dayr_input').val(),10));
      var bike = $('#bike').val();

      var price = calculatePrice(startDate,endDate,bike);
      $('#car-price').val(price);

  });
  $('#cars_input').change();
  });


  </script>
```

What I've done there is assign a variables, and then I tried to add the variables to variable array called priceMatrix, but it's not assigning somehow. I think that's because I'm assigning variable as it's done in jquery, could you please try help me fix the issue?

EDIT: JSFIDDLE Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tSsvb/2/

Comment: The cod  you posted seems fine in itself. You'll have to be more specific about what's going wrong (what isn't as you expected?), and provide more code context.

Comment: what is "carsinput"? A select? And are those custom attributes or what? I don't know why, but this code screams *for loop* to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're grabbing the data from the DOM, they're strings not numbers. You must force the numeric type by using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

Comment: So what? The variables should still get assigned, whether strings or integers.

Comment: Since your title mentions "calculation", you can't do math with strings.

Comment: According to jQuery:
`Note: Attribute values are strings with the exception of a few attributes such as value and tabindex.`

Comment: Notice that .attr() is not on that list.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your HTML.  However, I have a feeling it has to do with what you are trying to get out of the  tag:

```
($('#cars_input option[value="'+cars+'"]').attr('priceone'));
```

The above will get the value of the attribute "priceone".  For example, you would need it to be built like this to get `$12.00` using `.attr('priceone')`:

```
<option value="car-x" priceone="$12.00"> Car-X </option>
```

- if you want the value of the option, use `.val()`
- if you want the value of the ATTRIBUTE "priceone", use `.attr('priceone')`
- if you want the text within the option tag, use `.text()`

I hope this at least points you in the right direction!

Again, you should also post your HTML in questions like these to make it easier for us to see the big picture.

Answer (score 0):

`.attr('priceone'));`. `Priceone` is not an attribute .
You should call the atribute instead. Assuming it's an `ID` you should do: `.attr("id")`. That returns the string.